# Office : How to create a Spinner/Numeric up-down textbox?

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbon

I'm currently using Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) for MS Powerpoint 2013 in Visual C# to create a ribbon.

I want to create a Spinner or Numeric up/down textbox as shown below but I couldn't find any sort of plugin/tools to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't available in [2007 or 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/04dd2304-26e8-44dc-b2c8-2fc541738e86/how-to-add-a-spinner-spin-box-control-to-a-custom-ribbon-in-excel-2007?forum=exceldev) and that doesn't seem to have changed in 2013. That link does have a workaround though, using buttons.

```
<group id="Group1" label="Group1">
  <editBox id="Editbox1" label="Editbox1" getText="Editbox1_getText" onChange="Editbox1_onChange"/>
  <box boxStyle="vertical" id="Box1">
    <button id="spinUp" label="&#9650;" onAction="spin_onAction"/>
    <button id="spinDown" label="&#9660;" onAction="spin_onAction"/>
  </box >
</group >
```

[image]

It is fairly common to see controls used by an Office program that aren't available through VSTO, unfortunately.